# Issues with clearRect (canvas) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas

I have the following Code, when clicking on the Image the `clearRect()` should be clear the drawed elements, but it does not change anything. I have tried already with `context.beginPath()` which I have found as solution, but this working not in my case.

Plunker: [Testing the Code below](https://plnkr.co/edit/3geHWBlrFpQSdy9UN2I8?p=preview)

```
     //our root app component
        import {Component, ViewChild, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
        import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

        @Component({
          selector: 'my-app',
          template: `<h1>Angular 2 Systemjs start</h1>
            <img [src]="image" (click)="clearImage()">
          `
        })    
        export class App {
          image = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png';
          canvas : any;
          context : any;
          ngAfterViewInit() {

            this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

            let source = new Image(); 
            source.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
            source.onload = () => {

                // this.context.beginPath();

                this.canvas.height = source.height;
                this.canvas.width = source.width;
                this.context.drawImage(source, 0, 0);

                this.context.font = "100px impact";
                this.context.textAlign = 'center';
                this.context.fillStyle = 'black';
                this.context.fillText('TEST', this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height * 0.8);
                this.context.stroke();

                this.image = this.canvas.toDataURL();  

            };
            source.src = this.image;
          }


          clearImage()
          {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
          }


        }

        @NgModule({
          imports: [ BrowserModule ],
          declarations: [ App ],
          bootstrap: [ App ]
        })
        export class AppModule 

{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only one step behind - in fact, your `clearRect` works but you still need to update `this.image` to a new Data URL:

```
clearImage()
{
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.image = this.canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

Working Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/f4ram3h6yRQu7PtzcwLk?p=preview